# Defining the sample space when two players take turns rolling a fair die

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem:** Player A and Player B take turns rolling a fair die. If Player A rolls a $1$ or $2$ he wins and the game stops. If Player B rolls $3$, $4$, $5$, or $6$, she wins and the game stops. Suppose Player A rolls first. What is the probability that Player B wins and her last roll is a $4$?

**Solution:** Let $W$ be the event that Player B wins with a last roll of $4$ and let $W_n$ be the event that Player B wins on their $n$th roll. Then $W = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}W_n$.

In order for Player B to win on her $n$th roll, first Player A and Player B both fail $n-1$ times, then Player A fails once more, and then Player B succeeds with a $4$. Thus, by counting, we have that the ratio of favorable outcomes to the total number of alternatives gives us

$$
P[W_n] = \frac{4^{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot 4 \cdot 1}{6^n\cdot 6^n} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{8}{36}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^n.
$$

Hence, since the subevents $W_n$ are mutually exclusive, we have that

$$
P[W] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P[W_n] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{7}\right) = \frac{1}{7}.
$$

Note that this solution does not involve defining the sample space.

**Question:** How would I define the sample space $\Omega$ for this probability model and then compute the probability $P[W]$ using

$$
P[W] = \frac{|W|}{|\Omega|}
$$

instead where by $|W|$ I mean the size of $W$?

It seems to me that the sample space $\Omega$ is the set of all Cartesian products $S^n$ where $S = \{1,...,6\}$. The size of $\Omega$ is then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6^n$.

And the size of $W$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 4^{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot 4 \cdot 1$.

But then the probability $P[W]$ would be

$$
P[W] = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 4^{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot 4 \cdot 1}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6^n}
$$

which I don't see how that equals to $1/7$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $\Omega$ is meant to be the set of all possible games, then you have included far too many paths.  Or is $\Omega$ meant to be something else?

Comment: Should say, it is easier to work this out without sums.  There are two paths to a $B$ victory:  either $B$ wins on the first round, probability, $\left(\frac 46\right)^2$ or neither player wins on the first round and the game restarts.  Thus, if $p$ is the probability $B$ wins, we have $p=\left(\frac 46\right)^2+\frac 46\times \frac 26\times p\implies p=\frac 47$.  Since each individual outcome for $B$ is equally likely, the answer is then $\frac 17$ as desired.

Comment: @lulu It was meant to be the set of all possible outcomes by taking the union of all sets of one-roll possibilities, two-roll possibilities, three-roll possibilities, and so on.  But right, it includes possibilities that would not be games.  How do I adjust it?  Maybe that is my problem right there.

Comment: That's a big problem...you don't want to assign probabilities to paths that can not happen.

Comment: As I mentioned, I would not approach this by looking at paths.  Easier to use the fact that the game either ends in the first round or the game restarts from scratch.

Comment: @lulu I understand your solution, but I'm really looking for how to do the problem by defining the sample space.  I mean in your solution you are circumventing that by using independence of the rolls or something.  I know it's much easier this way, but I still want to know how to do this with the sample space being explicitly defined.

Comment: @lulu In your method, you say that Player B wins on their first roll with probability $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2$.  Isn't that using a "sample space" size of $36$ which also includes scenarios for two rolls that could never happen?

Comment: Not at all. In order for $B$ to win in the first round we need both players to throw one of $\{3,4,5,6\}$.  Thus there are $16$ total paths resulting in the desired outcome.

Comment: If you want to enumerate the paths, I'd describe them as $(HL)^nX$ where $H$ for "high" means one of $\{3,4,5,6\}$ and $L$ for "low" means one of $\{1,2\}$, and $X$ is either $L$ or $HH$.  Easy to count these and easy to compute their probabilities.

Comment: Should say:  this game is fairly simple, in that the possible paths can easily be described (as in my last comment).  It's easy to construct variants in which writing down all the possible paths is simply not practical.

Comment: @lulu I agree that $16$ is the number of desired outcomes, and that is your numerator, $4^2$.  It's your denominator I was alluding to.

Comment: I don't understand.  I am not counting paths here.  All those paths are victories for $B$, and each of them has probability $\frac 1{36}$.

Comment: For this first round of two rolls, you have that the probability is $16/36$.  Can't this be interpreted as the ratio of desired outcomes, $16$, over the total number of ways of rolling a die twice, $36$?

Comment: Well, I suppose that's the same as my remark that each of those paths has probability $\frac 1{36}$.  But keep in mind that those $36$ paths include paths like $1,1$ which can't happen (as the game would have ended on $A's$ first toss.)  But, sure.  Every fixed path of length $n$ has probability $6^n$.

Comment: @lulu That's my issue, and that's how I came up with my $\Omega$ in the post.

Comment: Ok, so you can define $\Omega$ to be the space of all paths if you want, but then you have to count the good ones, keeping track of their probabilities.  I think it is easier to focus on the good ones from the start.  But, never mind.  I understand what you were saying now (though not your calculations, which do not make sense).  You can do it the way you said if you don't mind counting.

Comment: So use my expression $(HL)^nHH$ which describes all winning paths for $B$.  Count the number of such expressions of a given length, and divide by the total number of paths of that length, and then sum.  You should reach [this calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%288%5E%28n-1%29*%284%5E2%29%29%2F6%5E%282n%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+infinity%7D%5D) for the probability of a $B$ victory.

Comment: @lulu That's exactly what I did in my solution in my post. What triggered me about it was that it felt like I was using different sample spaces for each scenario or something, and then summing up probabilities from different probability models.  It brought up my question of what really is the sample space here.

Comment: But your computation has terms like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6^n$ which do not make sense.  Doing it this way, you have to fix a length, compute the probability that the game ends with a path of that exact length, and then sum over the lengths.

Comment: @lulu See my "Solution" in my post, not my "Question".  Of course, my last factor in the numerator is a $1$, not a $4$, because we wanted a specific kind of win.

Comment: Ok, then I agree with that solution.  But not with what follows.  You can't treat infinite sets the same way you treat finite sets.  Writing $\frac {|W|}{|\Omega|}$ just has no clear meaning.

Comment: @lulu "Doing it this way, you have to fix a length, compute the probability that the game ends with a path of that exact length" -- This part I can't resolve in my head.  It's like we're computing probabilities in different models and then summing them up.  I did the same thing in my own solution.  It just bothers me that I can't define the sample space and then use the ratio approach like for a finite scenario.  I can't see exactly why.

Comment: The elements of $\Omega$ are not equally probable.  That's inevitable, as the set is infinite, but here we see that the probability depends on the length.  Same with $W$.  Naive counting arguments don't help much. This is why I prefer to define a sample space out of the winning paths alone.  Then you can just sum.

Comment: Sticking with your $\Omega$ think of it this way:  we pick a large $n$ and play the game for $n$ tosses.  Now there's no problem doing the weighted sum.  Of course there is a small chance that the game is unresolved, so the probabilities do not sum to $1$.  In the limit, however, they do.